# ViewPager muda a forma na qual um método funciona?

Tags: java, android

Eu criei um app que dá o valor de X e Y em um sistema linear de duas variáveis. Usando esses (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnlwBwMiFQw e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faegDgN7wX4) tutoriais, em um outro projeto, baseei-me no antigo e adicionei uma tab pra realizar o procedimento com três variáveis, sendo que o fragment que o faz ainda está vazio.
Pois bem, usei o mesmo método que faz o cálculo, fazendo as devidas declarações. O problema é que quando vai converter o elemento do EditText para String, o app para, sendo que o mesmo funciona perfeitamente no projeto antigo...

```
x = readX.getText().toString();
x2 = readX2.getText().toString();
y = readY.getText().toString();
y2 = readY2.getText().toString();
tInd = Ind.getText().toString();
tInd2 = Ind2.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Mains completas:
Projeto antigo: https://github.com/InsideMuz/SistemasLinearesS/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/insidemuz/sistemaslineares/Main.java
Projeto novo: https://github.com/InsideMuz/Justaproject/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/insidemuz/justaproject/MainActivity.java

Comment: Por favor, tente inserir o erro que está acontecendo na questão, para melhor entendimento.

Comment: Não entendi o seu problema...

Comment: Deve faltar `readX = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.......);`

Comment: Eu coloquei, ramaral, exatamente como está no antigo.

Comment: Pessoal, eu disponibilizei as duas mains caso vocês queiram ver se há algum inconsistência no código. O método que o onclick executa é o mathIt, e o app para logo após a conversão para string. Vou tentar providenciar um ADM pra executar o app e ver qual erro ele retorna.